# Running script after login

Tags: scripts, cron, startup, reboot

I want to run 2 different commands after login. One that changes sound card profile to HDMI since I'm using my laptop as a desktop connected to the TV and the other one that reloads specific gnome shell extensions, sleeps for 2 hours and then loops (one is causing memory leak and after reload everything is fine). Second script (extensions reload): I wrote it and made it executable and it works like it should when I run it. I tried with crontab (@reboot sh /complete/path/to/the/script/script.sh) and nothing. Sudo crontab, same results. "chmod 777 script.sh" and again with crontab, still nothing, without .sh suffix, nothing. Tried placing it in the /etc/init.d with same privileges as other scripts in the init.d directory (looked like this: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   ), update-rc.d script.sh defaults. Again, nothing. So I don't know what to do. The other script to set HDMI as audio output had the same problem but I managed to execute it on login by editing ~/.profile by just placing a command at the end of the file. After that I tried putting the command to run the second script (extensions) in ~/.profile file. That definitely didn't work as it was stuck at loading user infinitely (script loops itself). I deleted that second command from ~/.profile and it booted normally but again no sound through HDMI. It worked one time and now it doesn't work again. Since I don't need them to run at boot but after login, I tried to add them to startup applications and again nothing. I tried to put them in /etc/profile.d but again same story. What am I doing wrong. Can someone explain?

Comment: try putting them in `/etc/rc.local`. Also if you include the contents of `script.sh` we might spot an error.

Comment: The explanation of System Startup, User Environment Startup, GUI Startup, ... is Too Broad, but... Be aware that processes running through `crontab`, `root`'s `crontab (a different format), `/etc/init.d`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile.d` have different execution contexts - different userid, different `$PATH`, different environment variables, etc. They have access to diffferent resources, e.g. `/etc/init.d/foo` cannot manage the GUI because the Graphic User Interface has not been started when `/etc/init.d/foo` runs.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong."? You're stirring your system with a `root` stick - making changes you don't understand to an environment you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you for fast replies. I managed to set them to run as startup applications. The problem was I have Tilix as default terminal emulator and the scripts executed as soon as I opened new Tilix terminal window. So I reverted to the default gnome terminal and now they execute at login. My question now is why and how do I make this to work with Tilix as default emulator? And @waltinator: Isn't that exactly why these kind of forums exist in the first place? Also, I asked kindly what was wrong with what I did, asking for help, not bragging.